# A planning entity always violate a rule will cause a undoMove corruption?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I got a undoMove corruption exception while I plan a task schedule by Optaplanner with Chained Through Time pattern. I found that once a rule was violated, the undoMove corruption threw. I look into the planning entity, there is an entity always violate a rule due to its arrival time is later than delivery time. 
    In the rule "Task start time must later than its arrival time", it limits that the task's start time must later than its arrival time, and in the rule "Catch up delivery date", there is a punish score if a task's start time is later than its delivery time. So, if there is a task that its start time is later than delivery time, a UndoMove corruption appears.

```
rule "Task start time must later than its arrival time"
when 
    Task(
        $planStartTime : planStartTime != null,     // start time not null
        $arrivalTime : arrivalTime != null ,        // arrival time not null
        $planStartTime < $arrivalTime)              // start time earlier than arrival time
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,$planStartTime - $arrivalTime);
end

    rule "Catch up delivery date"
    when
        Task(
            $delTime : deliveryTime != null,        // the delivery time not null
            $endTime : getPlanEndTime() != null,    // task's end time not null, endTime = startTime + duration, and the startTime is the shadown variable. 
            $endTime > $delTime)                    // the taks's end time is later than its delivery time.
    then
           // once this constraint match, undoMove corruption exception throws.
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,  $delTime - $endTime );
    end
```

the trace stack:

```
08:42:37.140 [main] TRACE     Model annotations parsed for Solution TaskAssignmentSolution:
08:42:37.145 [main] TRACE         Entity Step:
08:42:37.146 [main] TRACE             Variable nextTask (shadow)
08:42:37.146 [main] TRACE         Entity Task:
08:42:37.146 [main] TRACE             Variable previousStep (genuine)
08:42:37.146 [main] TRACE             Variable machine (shadow)
08:42:37.146 [main] TRACE             Variable planStartTime (shadow)
08:42:39.086 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent (128), best score (-1init/0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (FULL_ASSERT), random (JDK with seed 0).
08:42:39.191 [main] TRACE         Corruption detected. Diagnosing...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UndoMove corruption: the beforeMoveScore (-1init/0hard/0medium/0soft) is not the undoScore (-1init/0hard/0medium/-1soft) which is the uncorruptedScore (-1init/0hard/0medium/-1soft) of the workingSolution.
  1) Enable EnvironmentMode FULL_ASSERT (if you haven't already) to fail-faster in case there's a score corruption.
  2) Check the Move.createUndoMove(...) method of the moveClass (class org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.chained.ChainedChangeMove). The move (Task [103-016] {null -> MachinePlan [1/FG-SG01/023]}) might have a corrupted undoMove (Undo(Task [103-016] {null -> MachinePlan [1/FG-SG01/023]})).
  3) Check your custom VariableListeners (if you have any) for shadow variables that are used by the score constraints with a different score weight between the beforeMoveScore (-1init/0hard/0medium/0soft) and the undoScore (-1init/0hard/0medium/-1soft).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertExpectedUndoMoveScore(AbstractPhaseScope.java:191)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.doMove(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:130)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:74)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:167)
    at com.esquel.APS.GEW_FN.solver.SolverManager.startSolve(SolverManager.java:359)
    at com.esquel.APS.GEW_FN.solver.SolveMain.planTasks(SolveMain.java:209)
    at com.esquel.APS.GEW_FN.solver.SolveMain.StartSolve(SolveMain.java:81)
    at com.esquel.APS.GEW_FN.main.App.main(App.java:84)
```

Do anyone know why? thanks advance.

Comment: I think I found why the rule "Catch up delivery date" was violated forever. The shadow variable startTime in planning entity task is updated by then event afterVariableChanged in the variable listener. In the method that calculates the startTime, there is logical that the value of starTime must be later than arrival time, so if there is a task that its arrival time later than delivery time, its start time must later than delivery time. the rule actually violates.

Comment: Does it mean, if there is an instance(planning entity or problem fact) leads to a rule violation forever, the undoMove corruption exception throw?

Comment: Did you enable EnvironmentMode FULL_ASSERT? (see the exception message). If that gives a different error, this is not an undo move corruption.

Comment: Yes, the environmentMode is FULL_ASSERT. There is a task always violates a rule, the exception thrown. When I change the task's field value let's inviolate, the exception disappeared.